# Native crash in libjsc.so with react native on Samsung S7 with Android 7

Tags: android, react-native, crash, native

We are using react native 0.59.1 in our app and it crashes on Samsung Galaxy S7 with Android 7 at launch time. Any other tested device (including other Samsungs and other devices with Android 7) works fine as well as Samsung S7 with Android 6 or 8. The crash appears only on S7 with Android 7.

Had tried to downgrade RN to 0.58 and other workarownds from these issues: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24260, https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24261 - none helped.

Can anybody explain me the reason for such behavior and help to fix this crash?

Here is the stack trace from logcat:

```
ASSERT|04-17 00:30:16.272|18763|18813||libc|Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xbbadbeef in tid 18813 (mqt_js)
ASSERT|04-17 00:30:16.402|18920|18920||DEBUG|Build fingerprint: 'samsung/heroltexx/herolte:7.0/NRD90M/G930FXXS1DQHF:user/release-keys'
ASSERT|04-17 00:30:16.402|18920|18920||DEBUG|*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
ASSERT|04-17 00:30:16.405|18920|18920||DEBUG|ABI: 'arm64'
ASSERT|04-17 00:30:16.405|18920|18920||DEBUG|Revision: '8'
ASSERT|04-17 00:30:16.406|18920|18920||DEBUG|pid: 18763, tid: 18813, name: mqt_js  >>> com.profibackoffice.reactnative <<<
ASSERT|04-17 00:30:16.406|18920|18920||DEBUG|signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xbbadbeef
ASSERT|04-17 00:30:16.407|18920|18920||DEBUG|    x16  00000070110b1acc  x17  000000700bc121a8  x18  0000000021ecfc88  x19  000000700fed7e80
ASSERT|04-17 00:30:16.407|18920|18920||DEBUG|    x20  00000070108cf560  x21  0000006ffd4c8070  x22  000000700bc00000  x23  0000006ff9616ca0
ASSERT|04-17 00:30:16.407|18920|18920||DEBUG|    x28  ffff000000000002  x29  00000070108cf560  x30  0000007011408484
ASSERT|04-17 00:30:16.407|18920|18920||DEBUG|    x24  0000000000000007  x25  0000000000000000  x26  0000000000000000  x27  ffff000000000000
ASSERT|04-17 00:30:16.407|18920|18920||DEBUG|    x8   00000000bbadbeef  x9   00000070114b19d0  x10  0000000000000000  x11  0000006ffc4f0000
ASSERT|04-17 00:30:16.407|18920|18920||DEBUG|    x0   00000070108cf3c8  x1   00000070108cf3c8  x2   0000000000000000  x3   00000000000000a8
ASSERT|04-17 00:30:16.407|18920|18920||DEBUG|    sp   00000070108cf400  pc   000000701140848c  pstate 00000000a0000000
ASSERT|04-17 00:30:16.407|18920|18920||DEBUG|    x4   000000700bfaee80  x5   0000006ff62a4980  x6   0000006ffa6a6820  x7   0000000000000000
ASSERT|04-17 00:30:16.407|18920|18920||DEBUG|    x12  0000000000000000  x13  000000700b617c00  x14  0000000000000002  x15  00000000bd36143d
ASSERT|04-17 00:30:16.412|18920|18920||DEBUG|backtrace:
ASSERT|04-17 00:30:16.412|18920|18920||DEBUG|    #03 pc 00000000001afe80  <anonymous:000000700bdff000>
ASSERT|04-17 00:30:16.412|18920|18920||DEBUG|    #02 pc 0000000000489f2c  /data/app/com.profibackoffice.reactnative-1/lib/arm64/libjsc.so (operationLinkDirectCall+1120)
ASSERT|04-17 00:30:16.412|18920|18920||DEBUG|    #01 pc 00000000000be650  /data/app/com.profibackoffice.reactnative-1/lib/arm64/libjsc.so (_Z16WTFCrashWithInfoiPKcS0_i+24)
ASSERT|04-17 00:30:16.412|18920|18920||DEBUG|    #00 pc 00000000007e048c  /data/app/com.profibackoffice.reactnative-1/lib/arm64/libjsc.so (WTFCrash+16)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround from https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24261 works. When I was trying this I've just removed `"arm64-v8a", "x86_64"` from another place and forgot the ndk block (I've removed the whole block earlier). So after adding these lines to build.gradle file crash dissappeared.

```
ndk {
   abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
}
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work for me, I have exact config you mentioned and it is crashing only on every physical device (tested in motoE2, Moto one power, samsung M20 and 2 other MI phones).

Comment: I have the same crash and tried all solutions from this post and it does not help me. Any new solutions?